# Grails Spring Security plugin - modify logged in user's authorities

Tags: security, spring, plugins, grails

I have a simple Grails app with Spring Security Core plugin installed and working fine. However, I haven't found any solution to the problem with updating a logged in user's authorities in the security context. I am not talking about updating the current user's details (i.e. springSecurityService.reauthenticate).

My problem is: I have a simple user management app with ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER authorities used. Now, I have 2 administrators logged in at the same time (with ROLE_ADMIN authority) from different computers, and one admin decides to change the other admin's authority from ROLE_ADMIN to ROLE_USER.

How can I update the user and role so that the modified user (with new ROLE_USER role) cannot perform any ROLE_ADMIN level actions and is immediately redirected to ROLE_USER level pages? Is there a way to update the security context so I don't have to do additional checking in all the controller actions whether the logged in user's authorities have been changed? Can I use the cahceUsers property for that somehow? I haven't modified the cacheUsers and in my understanding, it's false by default. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

EDIT: 
The sequence that's causing the problem is

1. Administrator "A" modifies administrator "B" and sets a new role (ROLE_USER) for administrator "B"
2. the code calls `PersonRole.removeAll(personInstanceB) and
   PersonRole.create(personInstanceB, roleAdmin)` and everything is updated normally
3. at the same time Administrator "B" is already logged in when their authorities are modified. Administrator "B" can continue working on ROLE_ADMIN restricted pages until he/she logs out and does a new login. Only then the authorities are updated and Administrator "B" has the new role (ROLE_USER)
4. I want Administrator "B" to be redirected to the ROLE_USER pages when the user is updated with the new role and not only after logout/login
5. calling `springSecurityService.reauthenticate personInstanceB.username)` causes Administrator "A" to be "logged in" as Administrator "B" so this does not work.

Any ideas would be very welcome. I may have missed something simple here but I have no idea what the solution would be.

Cheers,
mizzzto

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is untested but give it a try

In your controller/service class,

```
...

User user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id) //get the user
Role adminRole = //get or create the admin Role
UserRole.remove user, role // remove admin Role

Role userRole = // get or create the user Role
UserRole.create user, role //add the user Role

... 

if (!user.hasErrors() && user.save(flush: true)) {
    springSecurityService.reauthenticate user.username // refresh the users security deatils
}

....
```

## EDIT

That is a lot clearer now.

What I would do off the top of my head is use the switch user function. see [Switch User](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#15%20Switch%20User)

- First you set the `useSwitchUserFilter` attribute to `true`
- It is advised you make a new role(e.g `ROLE_SWITCH_USER`) for this priviledge.
- in your admin page somewhere,

  ```
  <sec:ifAllGranted roles='ROLE_SWITCH_USER'>
     <form action='/j_spring_security_switch_user' method='POST'>
        Switch to user: <input type='text' name='j_username'/> <br/>
        <input type='submit' value='Switch'/>
     </form>
  </sec:ifAllGranted>
  ```
- log in as the user you wish to edit using their username
- change their role settings by making a call to the `adminToUser()` method below(for example)
- switch back to the original user
- Done.

--
You can use the code form the first answer to create a method in your controller or service that take a userInstance and changes thier role from admin to user.

```
def adminToUser(user, adminRole, userRole){
    UserRole.remove user, adminRole
    UserRole.create user, userRole 
    if (!user.hasErrors() && user.save(flush: true)) {
        springSecurityService.reauthenticate user.username 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Before posting my question I had already done as you described. However, this means that if you are an admin and you update another admin's authority -> then calling springSecurityService.reauthenticate user.username will cause the session to be updated with the modified user's credentials. And that means you have just "logged in" as the user you have modified. I don't want that :) I will edit my post to make it more clear on what I'm after.

Comment: thanks a lot, seems to be working fine now, so simple and yet very powerful! :) Although, there really should be some easier way to notify the modified user that their authorities have been changed while the user is logged in. I need to get to the bottom of this :)

Comment: @mizzzto No probs! There might be an easier way to achieve this... if you find something do post it up!

Comment: wouldn't the ideal solution be: `SpringSecurityUtils.doWithAuth(otherUsername) { springSecurityService.reauthenticate(otherUsername) }`?  Can't seem to get it working though...

Answer (score 7):

I have solved this problem by reauthenticating twice:

Save the name of the administrator who is demoting the other user:

```
def originalUserName = springSecurityService.principal.name
springSecurityService.reauthenticate user.username
springSecurityService.reauthenticate originalUserName
```