# Grails spring security ui: create different users with different roles on Registration

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using Spring security core & Spring security UI in my project. I have a requirement in which i need to create 2 different type of users: Sellers and Buyers. When user goto home page he can select what type of account he wants to create either buyer or seller.

What i have to do it make it work with spring security UI plugin. Do i have to create different Registration pages for different type of users. But then how i can assign roles at the time of registration.

I checked various questions posted before posting this question and could not find the right answer. I am new to Grails and will appreciate if Grails experts can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your question, I was a bit confused about mixing login with registration in your question.

Once you have created your user create `UserRole` based on the selected role, either `ROLE_BUYER or ROLE_SELLER`. This can be done in `UserController create` method.

As for login you don't need to have two different logins, you can always create a filter, interceptor, or any aspect oriented technique to intercept the request and redirect user to the proper section of your site. This way you're authorization is loosely coupled. Imho, there is no need to use Spring Security UI for authorization specific goals. Spring Security Core does much better job wrt url mapping/annotations.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to amend UserController.

Comment: Found this thread. It solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409548/grails-spring-security-plugin-modify-logged-in-users-authorities